# How to check if the end of a string is equal to any of the strings in an Arraylist in Java

Tags: java

For example, if I were to do this for a single input then it will be

```
boolean Ends = current.endsWith(Input);

if (Ends == true) {
    success = true;
}
```

`current` is the string. I need to see if the end of current is any of the entries in the array list  preferably if it could be a Boolean.

Answer (score -1):

```
String suffix = "sd";
boolean isEnds = Arrays.asList("dasdas","Dssdsd").stream().anyMatch(s->s.endsWith(suffix));
```

Comment: This is doing things backwards.